# Client-side added behavior

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, serialization, client-server

'm trying to design a system where a class would be defined in a project, be referenced in another and have new functionalities in the latter. Is there a pattern for this?

Context: I have a game that has items in a common project. Both the server and client reference this same project so I can have the item StaffItem in both the server and client, making it easier to serialize and deserialize between the two. The problem is, I can't redefine the StaffItem class in the client, since it will change the server's perspective of this class. I'm trying to find a nice way to add, for instance, the rendering to the client-side view of the class (added code for textures and all that).

I'm almost at the point of giving up and simply putting the rendering code in the common project, and stubbing it for the server. Any pointers (hehe) would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to understand the problem, why would creating a child class on the client that inherits from the `StaffItem` class not work?

Comment: "problem is, I can't redefine the StaffItem class in the client"   Redifine how? Why?

Comment: Well @iuliu.net I'm trying to keep the same class because I will use this for my serialization. I will assign IDs to the types. I guess I could use a subclass, and change the way my serialization work...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of transferring the actual objects over the wire, you could introduce a DTO class for serializing and deserializing. This decouples the actual implementations on both sides.

Comment: +1, but expand the answer. Explain about why it's a good idea to not rely on the communication protocol/objects in the business domain. Explain why strong coupling makes it harder to improve code quality later on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, there are two options you may consider. First one is to use smth similar with decorator pattern:

```
class StaffItem : IStaffItem {
  public int MyProp {get;set;}
  public void MyAction() {}
}
class ClientStaffItem : IStaffItem {
  private StaffItem _staffItem;
  public ClientStaffItem(StaffItem staffItem) {
    _staffItem = staffItem;
  }
  public int MyProp {
        get { return _staffItem.MyProp;} 
        set {_staffItem.MyProp; = value;}
  }
  public void MyAction() {
    _staffItem.MyAction();
  }
  public void YouClientMethod() {}
}
```

The other one use inheritance, but determine which fields you need to serialize and how and use attributes or custom serialization settings to mark only properties you need.